# SEND DATA FROM JS to python

Tags: javascript, python

Newbie alert!!!
Need help in sending data from json to python

this is an extract from my HTML script trying to send data to python...how do I receive it in python?

```
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="U" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">UP</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="D" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">DOWN</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="L" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">LEFT</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="R" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">RIGHT</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="F" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">FRONT</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="B" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">BACK</button>
        <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="M" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px">MAGFI</button>


 </span>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('.my_button').mousedown(function () {
                //Comment the alert mesage this is for testing to make sure the values are captured
                alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
                var buttonVal = $(this).attr('data-value');
                var param = buttonVal;
                //URL put the reference of the Python script for mouse down event.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/home/pi/mousedown.py",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: param,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: You should use a web framework. There are [many options](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

Comment: It is true there are many frameworks, but something like _Flask_ may be a good start. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/views/

Answer (score 0):

I would have created Flask REST Api in python to be able to receive data:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home/pi", methods = ['POST'])
def pi():
    data = request.form['data']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

with slight change in your post request:

from:

```
url: "/home/pi/mousedown.py"
```

to:

```
url: "/home/pi"
```

Comment: is that a flask rest api or just a normal flask app?

Comment: I wanted it to get data from the webpage on 192.168.1.19:80
when i changed the app.run() to app.run(host='192.168.1.19',port='80')
Getting an error " socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

Please help me out again

Comment: @AayushBasavesh you need to put  host='0.0.0.0'. Can you please mark my previous answer correct, if it helped :) Thanks

Comment: Otherwise it is running on port 5000

Comment: All my files are in /var/www/HTML                              So I’ve changed the route in the API accordingly to “/var/www/HTML”